# How to write wrapper R file for executing .sh file

Tags: python, r, shell, sh

My aim is to invoke a python model using this shell. Is there a way to make a wrapper R file to execute this sh file?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to run a OS command is function `system2`.

```
system2("sh", args = "model.sh")
```

---

If the file `model.sh` is in the home directory and its contents are as below:

```
# file: model.sh
pwd
cd $1
pwd
cd $2
pwd
cd ~
```

the command `"sh"` followed by *all* arguments, the script name and its arguments, will change directory twice and then change back to the home directory `"~"`.

```
system2(command = "sh", args = c("model.sh", "tmp", "tmp"))
#/home/rui
#/home/rui/tmp
#/home/rui/tmp/tmp

getwd()
#[1] "/home/rui"
```

If the script is to be made an executable, which can be done from an R command line

```
system2(command = "chmod", args = c("+x", "model.sh"))
```

then the first argument to `system2` is the command (the script file) and the script's arguments are passed on in `args`.

```
system2(command = "./model.sh", args = c("tmp", "tmp"))
#/home/rui
#/home/rui/tmp
#/home/rui/tmp/tmp

getwd()
#[1] "/home/rui"
```

Return to previous permissions.

```
system2(command = "chmod", args = "-x model.sh")
```

Any system command can be run like this, see [`help("system2")`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system2.html).

The vector of arguments can be a single character string like the last `chmod` command above or a vector with each argument in order.

```
system2("chmod", args = c("-x", "model.sh"))
```

In this case, the return value of `system2` is the OS command error code.

```
res <- system2(command = "ls", args = c("-l", "model.sh"))
#-rwxrwxr-x 1 rui rui 45 fev  7 07:24 model.sh

res
#[1] 0
```

To have the command return a character vector of its output, set `stdout = TRUE`.

```
system2(command = "chmod", args = c("+x", "model.sh"))
main_sh <- system2(command = "./model.sh",
                   args = c("model.py","x.json"),
                   stdout = TRUE
)
```

See the help page section `Value` for further details on the return value.

Comment: How to pass in name of the file and the json file as a parameter to the sh file

Comment: @James See if the edit answers the question.

Comment: all my working directory is in the current working directory of R. 
Is this correct way of doing.. the shell is an execuatbale file and the arguments are python filename and the 2nd argument is the json file   
main_sh <- system2("sh", "+x model.sh", args(c("model.py","x.json")))

Comment: @James Yes, that's it. Pass the executable as first argument or as a named argument, `command = "model.sh"`, then a vector of arguments to `model.sh`.

Comment: Like this main_sh <- system2(command = "model.sh", args(c("model.py","x.json"))) ?

Comment: @James Yes, see the edit, I believe it's more clear now.

Comment: Last question, sorry to bother but is there a way to output what u get in main_sh to a text file?

Comment: @James Yes, there's base R `writeLines` and `write.table`, depending on what you get.

Comment: When i try only this command it works"system2(command = "sh", args = c("+x", "model.sh"))" but when I try to use this "main_sh <- system2(command = "./model.sh",
                   args = c("model.py","x.json"),
                   stdout = TRUE
)"
I get error "Error in system2(command = "./model.sh", args = c("model.py"), stdout = TRUE) : 
  'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\Users\james\document\model.sh model.py'   "

Comment: @James Sorry! It was a bug, it's `command = "chmod"`, **not** `"sh"`.

Comment: My shell script invokes a python model which accepts a parameter. But how to put this chmod in :
main_sh <- system2(command = "./model.sh",
                   args = c("model.py","x.json"),
                   stdout = TRUE
)
before it was executing for system2(command = "sh", args = c("+x", "model.sh")) now its not executing i guess

Comment: @James You must first make the script executable with chmod, then execute the command sh with the python model and parameter. The last two instructions in my answer must be run one after the other.

Comment: I am getting the same error again.
> system2(command = "chmod", args = c("+x", "model.sh"))
> main_sh <- system2(command = "./model.sh",
+ args = c("test_json.txt"),
+ stdout = TRUE
+ )
Error in system2(command = "./model.sh", args = c("test_json.txt"), :
'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\Users\james\document\model.sh test_json.txt'

This is the code I have put in now :
system2(command = "chmod", args = c("+x", "model.sh"))
main_sh <- system2(command = "./model.sh",
args = c("text_json.txt"),
stdout = TRUE
)

Comment: @James 1) Are the paths correct? The command `./model.sh` implies that the script is in your working directory; 2) When run on the command line (no R) does it work? This last comment is different from the others, have you tested it?

Comment: I have done getwd() and saw its in the same folder which is the document folder. All the files in document folder. Can you see if it works for u. 

i am still getting error for this :
system2(command = "chmod", args = c("+x", "model.sh"))
main_sh <- system2(command = "./model.sh",
                   args = c("model.py"),
                   stdout = TRUE
)